# To take the input through form and store into database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have created a drop down menu where, if user opens link 1 it directs it into form containing 3 text boxes.

In the same way with link 2 will contain 5 text boxes.

It's totally depend's upon user request. Each may contain different no of text boxes. So now I need to save input from form automatically in database, 
when ever user press submit!!!!.

Form input must be saved in database.

Can be any language and any type of database I will learn.

Any help will be highly appreciated!!.

Thank you

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @SloanThrasher well i've  tried all i can google. all i wanted to know is can i do this or not! if yes in which language etc. if not any alternative. i don't need code all i need is assistance

Comment: Yes, you can do it, and you can use any language you like that can access MySQL. Your question is way too broad. SO is not a code writing service. I'm sure there are plenty of programmers that will write the code for you for a fee. Look at the links in my comment, that will explain why your question isn't appropriate on StackOverflow.

Comment: @SloanThrasher i am not asking about accessing database ..i want to store in database hope u have seen question correctly.i know we can access or add details in database but thing is that by which programming language i can store input form values as mentioned in my question

Comment: If you want to store in a database, your code will have to have access to a database (duh!). You question is not appropriate on SO. Follow the links in my 1st comment to see why.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, form "submission" leads to another web page, carrying the values in the form either in $_GET or $_POST.  Clue it in thus: `<form action=next.php method=POST>` (or `method=GET`).

That other web page should do several steps.

1. Connect to the database.  (The previous page's connection is gone.)
2. Parse the args.
3. Build `INSERT` statements (or whatever).  Recommend studying the "mysqli" and/or "PDO" set of routines.
4. Perform them.

You did not say anything that indicated the necessity of AJAX.